# Bootstrap Tooltip showing at top left of page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap Tooltip in my application. The tooltip comes but its missing its CSS. It comes at left top with no formatting.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip" id="example" data-placement="top">Hover over me</a>

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#example").tooltip();            
        });
</script>
```

I tried solutions like this 1, But had no effect :-

```
<style>
        .tooltip-inner {
            color: red;
            background-color: orange;
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }
</style>
```

I have serached all my `CSS` for any other `class` which have similar name with `tooltip-inner` which might be overriding the bootstrap class, but i found none.

One thing i noticed, when i hover on the link, in `Inspect element` I found this property added to the link :-

```
aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-12"

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" id="example" data-placement="top" aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-13">Hover over me</a>
```

Every Help is Appreciated.

Comment: default code of `tooltip` plugin requires `rel` attribute too, although you can change it and `rel` attr seems to be missing or if you could post the tooltip code too in your question or [try adding any fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: please give fiddle replicating your problem!! :)

Comment: In fiddle it will work 100%, Its not working in my application.. :)

Comment: @Anup : have you tested it already in fiddle??? then may b some code conflict in your source code is causing it!!

Comment: @NoobEditor Comeon...I am not a beginner... ;)

Comment: @Anup : yeah..that i know....but still, a working demo for a problem is always a welcome gesture!! ;)

Comment: @jai http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage Don't find any `rel` here..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what was causing the issue.

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
```

I removed this & it worked. The Jquery UI tooltip & Bootstrap tooltip both included were dis aligning the tooltip.

Comment: This jquery file we need to support lots of extra functionalities .. Is there any workaround you got except this ?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the position of the
`Jquery UI` javascript
above the 
`Bootstrap UI` js
will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that i called the $().tooltip method while the element was hidden, so bootstrap couldn't get the position.
Be sure to call .tooltip() after the element is shown